# add class to alternate items and restart for each container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a series of divs with class '.collection-list'. Within each one I need to add a class to every other child div '.streamItem'. These are loaded via an ajax call on a click event.

The problem I am having is that the class is being added to every other '.streamItem' from the top of the page on down. What I want is for the alternating to start and end within each parent '.collection-list' without effecting the others.

The goal is a two column layout for which which I need to add a different class for the items in the right column, but The first item should never have that class.

Here is what I have so far which is failing to do what I have in mind:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('.collection-list').each(function(index) {
        $('.streamItem:even').addClass('right');
    })
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle Demo Would be appreciated

Comment: Each of these .collection-list divs toggle open after loading the contents via ajax. This example works correctly (changing even to odd) when only one of these panels is open, but when I open a new one, it changes the order of the classes added on previously opened panels.

Comment: Fiddle helps to get a better look into the problem ,thanks to @TrueBlueAussie he made a mockup of html layout

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for an each loop:

```
$('.collection-list').find('.streamItem:even').addClass('right');
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vZdLc/

Basically the `find` is applied to each `collection-list`, but only matching the even `streamItem`s within each.

Answer (score 0):

You should  modify the selector to target only child elements of current div in `.each()` loop:

```
$('.collection-list').each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('.streamItem:even').addClass('right');
});
```

or

```
$('.collection-list').each(function(index) {
    $('.streamItem:even',this).addClass('right');
})
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think `:even` is [supported](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) in IE8-.

Comment: @cr0ss: that is different concern.

Comment: @cr0ss That's CSS selectors, jQuery uses fallbacks to allow legacy support

Comment: These both work, but you do not need an `each` loop at all for this problem. Added alternate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `.each()` to addClass check out my answer and `$(this)` was what you were missing  in your code

### Jquery

```
     $('.streamItem:even').each(function() {
              $(this).addClass('right');
         });
```

### CSS

```
.right{
    color: green;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="collection-list">
    <div class="streamItem">item 1</div>
    <div class="streamItem">item 2</div>
    <div class="streamItem">item 3</div>
</div>

<div class="collection-list">
    <div class="streamItem">item 1</div>
    <div class="streamItem">item 2</div>
    <div class="streamItem">item 3</div>
    <div class="streamItem">item 4</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vZdLc/5/)

### For this Output

[image: O/p1]

---

Use This Code

```
         $( "div.streamItem:nth-child(odd)" ).addClass('right');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vZdLc/4/)

### For this Output

[image]

---

Use This Code

```
         $( "div.streamItem:nth-child(even)" ).addClass('right');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vZdLc/6/)

### Was This Output Which you were getting and wanting to change to one among the above two

[image: O/p3]

---

```
$('div.streamItem:even').each(function() {
                $(this).addClass('right');
          
          });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vZdLc/5/)

Comment: This does not actually do what the asker wanted (the "evens" should restart per collection-list). *You have taken my working JSFiddle and broken it!* Well done :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Sorry for that i was also working on it and since you posted your answer i thought i could borrow your HTML and CSS If you want it i shall delete it

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but you have only duplicated the original asker's problem, *not solved it* :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Solved it

Comment: Not sure why you made them more complex, but as I pointed out you do not even need an `each` :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Just edited My Fiddle and added code in each and i have changed it